# How to set tabbar in bottom of the screen in Android?

Tags: android, layout, tabbar, tabwidget, android-framelayout

Currently i am working tabbar application in Android. here i mentioned the code for your reference, I refer the web, some of the links Found (android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true") insert this line in TabWidget, but the tabbar visible in Top only, so please help me

Thanks in Advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#EBF1FF">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  =========> android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" <=======
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: [Try this once](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom) and also [An stylish TabHost in Bottom](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"` works only if the `TabWidget` is inside a `RelativeLayout`..

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then, how to fix this. do u have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `TabWidget` **after** the `FrameLayout`.

And use `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` to hide the strip under the tabwidget because it looks ugly when it's on the bottom.